# vagrant + Permission denied Mint

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I fight with it only 2 days. I see many similar post but i can't solve my problem.

I have Mint 18 as main OS (4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linu) and now I have:

- virtualbox 5.0.40 r115130
- Vagrant 1.8.4 + vagrant-vbguest (0.14.2)

Vm installed correctly. When I try run "vagrant ssh" I see:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

My config:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.106"
  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/home/vagrant'  
end
```

Synced_folder works correct.

vagrant ssh-config

```
 Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/wiktor/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject1/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

And:
ssh -i /home/wiktor/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject1/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key -v vagrant@localhost -p 2222

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wiktor/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject1/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wiktor/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject1/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wiktor/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wiktor/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wiktor/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wiktor/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wiktor/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wiktor/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wiktor/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wiktor/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wiktor/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wiktor/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:2222 as 'vagrant'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:bfFoWuZbyskLe9SNF07Qkt6biJYCFhn83Yxy4RAIiGw
debug1: Host '[localhost]:2222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/wiktor/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wiktor/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject1/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wiktor/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wiktor/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wiktor/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wiktor/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wiktor/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I don't understand this error. Maybe vagrant can't generate public key.

After connect to VM through VirtualBox and runed "ls -la /home/vagrant" I didn't see directory ".ssh". Is that correct?

I tried to run virtualbox 5.1 and vagrant 1.8.5 but I have the same errors.

When I used Windows10 after incorrect public/private key, this requested a password to the vagrant user. 
On Mint returns the error. I changed chmod and edited /etc/ssh/sshd_config on guest and main OS. It's didn't help.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is due to the below line in your vagrantfile

```
  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/home/vagrant'
```

The `authorized_keys` file for the vagrant user is located in `/home/vagrant/.ssh` inside the vagrant machine, which enables to ssh into the vagrant box.

As you are mounting your current directory to `/home/vagrant`, all the contents of `/home/vagrant` are over-written and there is no `authorized_keys` file.

Change the mount path to anything except `/home/vagrant`, and you will able to ssh into the machine. As example

```
  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/home/vagrant/somepath'
```

Comment: dude you are a legend, been banging my head coz of this.